# Material-ui [Chip] On hover show delete icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have been trying to get the on-hover property of the chip. The desired response should be like, when I hover on a chip from a chip array, it should show the delete icon.

I have attached the snippet:-

```
  chip: {
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: darken(
        theme.palette.primary.main,
        theme.palette.action.hoverOpacity * 3,
      ),
    },
  },
            <Chip
              className={classes.chip}
              key={i}
              label={tag.label}
              size="small"
              color={state.edit === false ? "primary"
                : tag.to_del ? "secondary"
                  : tag.is_new ? "primary"
                    : "default"}
              onDelete={state.edit === true ? ((e) => state.deleteTag(i)) : undefined}
              // onMouseEnter={}
              onMouseDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
            />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the implementation using CSS to show the delete icon in the chip on hover.

[Working demo in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-chip-with-delete-icon-on-hover-3m0t4?file=/demo.js)

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  chip: {
    "& .MuiChip-deleteIcon": {
      display: "none"
    },
    "&:hover": {
      "& .MuiChip-deleteIcon": {
        display: "block"
      }
    }
  }
}));
```

```
const classes = useStyles();

<Chip
  color="primary"
  label={data.label}
  onDelete={handleDelete(data)}
  className={classes.chip}
/>
```

Comment: This is more clean approach, if using the chip css overloads.

Comment: This is not recommended, you are bypassing the component's API and modifying its styling directly via jss.  As MUI migrates from jss to emotion during V5, this approach will be deprecated in the future.

Comment: @DavidI.Samudio I'm just creating a new CSS class and passing it to the Chip component. So I feel this approach is perfectly fine because it doesn't override anything in the Chip component. Also, this example works perfectly fine with the next version (v5) of Material UI.

Comment: You are not passing the class to the MUI component but the HTML component, try passing them via the `classes` prop. Global selectors may change (`.MuiChip-deleteIcon"`), modifying them (future MUI releases) may potentially and silently break your code, and unnecessary because a show / hide option is already available via API. It is not about code brevity, it's about code maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you are only missing the mouse enter and leave bindings to handle your delete logic:

```js
  const [state, setState] = useState({ edit: false});
  const handleMouseEnter = () => setState(state=>({...state, edit: true }));
  const handleMouseLeave = () => setState(state=>({...state, edit: false }));

  <Chip
    // ...
    onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
    onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
  />;
```

I made the changes to get the behavior you are looking for (as shown above):

https://codesandbox.io/s/chips-material-demo-forked-9f1u4?file=/demo.js

Comment: Thanks. I got the logic. But I am having one more question if the chip is an array then state. edit =true will be applied to all the chips, which is not ok. The delete icon is shown where there is a hover event. How I can prevent this action.

Comment: I have made edits to the code [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/chips-material-demo-forked-ro9uh?file=/demo.js)

Comment: that is a different question altogether, I made changes to my pastebin to include that.